# Intelligence and Entropy

Tags: energy, entropy

Is intelligence an entropy transformer?
and the difference between a lower and higher intelligence is the efficiency?

Comment: Define "intelligence."

Comment: a proper definition is difficult maybe an energy focusing and steering force

Comment: Hi Rob, welcome to Physics SE. Although your question might be interesting speculation, it does not fall into the standard physics knowledge, and as such wont go very far here. For more info about this website style and content, I invite you to browse some questions and take the tour here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: perhaps related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_information_theory

Comment: Is boiling water intelligent? According to your hypothesis it should be. Lots and lots of entropy gets generated in a boiling pot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entropy has various uses in Physics. It was first used as a state variable for thermodynamics, connected to energy and heat. Later, it was revealed that entropy is a measure of the disorder of a system. By extension, it is a measure of the observer's ignorance or lack of expectation about the precise, microscopic state of a system. This in turn is related to the modern connection between entropy and information: the higher the entropy of a string of data, the higher the information that can be transmitted.

In turn, there is no precise definition of "intelligence" in physics. Thus your idea of intelligence as entropy transformer is very speculative. There is much that you can read from here, probably in both information theory and computer science. Maybe you can start from [this amazing book](http://www.inference.eng.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html).

Comment: The notion of entropy in information theory and of that in physics is not the same. Physical entropy has to be zero at $T=0$. Information entropy does not have this property, so they are not the same. In my opinion they are not even related except trough a rather vacuous argument resting entirely on similarity.

Comment: @CuriousOne definitely their use rarely overlaps. But the statistical physics' entropy of the micro-states does correspond to the information-theoretic entropy. In some sense the relation is how much data you need to provide to completely specify the micro state of a certain macrostate. I think the main difference isn't physical vs information theoretic but thermodynamic vs physical.

Comment: Physics is a theory of dynamics systems. You can not reduce it to the statistics or even combinatorics of static configurations. The third law of thermodynamics won't let that happen. Physical entropy is one thing, information entropy is another and the name of the latter is chosen poorly. They should have called it something else. Shannon surely would have know that he was making a poor choice there... the question (to the science historians) is, if Shannon made that choice. I suspect not, but whoever introduced the term didn't do anybody a favor.

Comment: Physics cannot be reduced to statistics. But the Boltzmann entropy does correspond to the Shannon entropy for microstates of systems in  thermal equilibrium.

Comment: A system in thermal equilibrium is characterized (among other things) by its temperature... and the entropy depends on it explicitly. There is just no logical way that you can make a function that depends on T into one that doesn't. Information entropy is simply a reductionist view that fundamentally breaks the meaning of physical entropy. I am not saying its meaningless. Of course it isn't, it's just not the same.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am (honestly) interested in your view. In university we get taught that T is dependent on the statistics of the particles. T as an emergent property, or as you would say perhaps: the reductionist definition of temperature. If I understand correctly, you are viewing T as fundamental, and the statistics are secondary? Perhaps we can move this conversation to a private chat.

Comment: Let's put it this way: in a world where they discover codes first and they have information processing machines and they understand information entropy and all that, but they don't have physics, yet. They will always have to wonder how one gets from one state to another, because no amount of combinatorics does that, right? One day somebody discovers physics and then thermodynamics and suddenly the actual meaning of information entropy becomes clear because now they can see how physical entropy works and how dynamic systems select states. We just did it the other way round... :-)

Comment: As for temperature: we had that explained very nicely in another question, wish I could find it. You can look at it as a Lagrange multiplier and it's  always proportional to an energy trough $k_BT$. In that sense it's not an independent quantity. However, and this is important, the mere existence of a temperature depends on the system being in near thermodynamic equilibrium. That is a non-trivial property and one which actually counteracts the information theoretical view. Machines in thermal equilibrium can not calculate anything! Information theory is only possible far from equilibrium.